# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed - Converting Base64 (video/mp4) to Blob in React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, base64, expo, blob

I am trying to get a file from my phone to convert it into javascript File object but to do that I need it to be a blob first. Here is my code so far:

```
import * as FS from 'expo-file-system';

let base64 = await FS.readAsStringAsync('file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/b914bf57-4899-45d1-a020-fc2b274b4640.mp4', {encoding: FS.EncodingType.Base64});
let base64Response = await fetch(`data:video/mp4;base64,${base64}`);
let blob = await base64Response.blob();
let file = new File([blob], "video.mp4", {type: "video/mp4"});
```

How can I make this work or is there an easier way to do it? I couldn't find any working examples that would work for me. The exception is raised on the first Fetch() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using DocumentPicker, here is my code:

```
const { type, uri } = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
            copyToCacheDirectory: false,
            type: 'video/mp4',
          });
      
if (type === 'cancel') {
  return;
}
              
const fetchResponse = await fetch(uri);    
const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();  
file = new File([blob], "video.mp4", {type: "video/mp4"});
```